# Showing a function's derivative changes signs infinitely often?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I had to come up with a function that has a global minimum, has to approach infinity and its derivative changes signs infinitely often on $[0, \infty]$. I came up with $x^2(\sin(x))^2$.

I showed it had a global minimum since its range is $[0, \infty]$, and the fact that it has $0's$ on $0, \pi, 2\pi, 3\pi ,\ldots n\pi$. I then used the first derivative test to confirm these points were minimums.

However, I am having trouble showing its derivative changes infinitely often on $[0, \infty]$. I know $f'(x) = 2x \sin^2(x) + 2x^2 \sin(x) \cos(x)$.

From there, we know that from $[0, \infty]$, $2x \sin^2(x) \ge 0$ and $2x^2  \sin(x) \cos(x)$ changes signs since $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ oscilate. What can I do from here? I don't see the first or second derivative tests helping that much.

Comment: Since the function is continuous, and has infinitely many minima, then...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but ... Since (as you know) the function has zeroes at integer multiples of $\pi$, it does not satisfy the "approach infinity" requirement. (Presumably, the formal requirement is that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$. The definition of the infinite limit is that, for any $N > 0$, there is an $x_N$ such that $f(x) > N$ **for all** $x>x_N$. That is, at some finite threshold, the function gets bigger than $N$ ---whatever $N$ may be--- and never again dips below $N$. However, your function always returns to zero beyond any finite threshold one might choose.)

Comment: $f'(x) = 0 \therefore \sin(x) = - x \cos(x)$ which has solutions which approach pi apart as they get larger.

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, f(k \pi) = 0$$
$$\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, f\left(k\pi+\frac{\pi}2\right)=c_k >0$$

Hence   $\exists a_k \in \left(k \pi, k\pi +\frac{\pi}2  \right)$, such that $f'(a_k) >0$, otherwise, we would have $f\left(k\pi+\frac{\pi}2\right)\le f(k\pi)=0.$

Similarly, $\exists d_k \in \left( k\pi +\frac{\pi}2, (k+1)\pi  \right)$, such that $f'(d_k) <0$, otherwise, we would have $0=f((k+1)\pi) \ge f\left(k\pi+\frac{\pi}2\right).$

Hence, the derivative changes sign infinitely often.